# Что такое :zone_identifier в cloudflare api?

Tags: api, облако

При запросах они требуют вставлять в *url* свой *api-key* и какой-то *zone_identifier*, но что это такое, они не говорят нигде.

Answer (score 2):

[цитата и мой вольный перевод](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-tips-frequently-used-cloudflare-ap/):

1. You will need to get your API key for your account first. You can locate the API key by going to your 'My Account' page.

   вначале вам необходимо получить *api key*. найти его можно на странице [*my account*](https://www.cloudflare.com/my-account.html).
2. Each zone (yourdomain.com) on CloudFlare has a unique number identifier. If you need to locate the zoneid for a domain, simply go to the "Reports and Stats' link for that domain (the zone id appears at the end with an equal sign, such as zid=xxxxxx).

   каждая зона (вашдомен.рф) в *cloudflare* обладает уникальным цифровым идентификатором. найти этот *zoneid* можно, перейдя по ссылке (вероятно, на странице аккаунта) *reports and stats* для этого домена — *zoneid* вы увидите в конце адресной строки: `zid=xxxxxx`.

**Обновление**

я думаю, данное название приведено в качестве иллюстрации. если у вас зарегистрирован домен на их сайте, просто посмотрите на *url*-ы, которые ведут на страницы, относящиеся к этому домену. наверняка где-то там должно встретиться что-то подобное в адресе: с символами `z`, `id`, `=` и набором цифр.

Comment: К сожалению там такого нет, reports and stats

Comment: Хорошая идея попробую! Отпишусь

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую в админке CloudFlare мне не удалось найти `zone id` для моего домена, однако его можно получить если сделать запрос по CloudFlare api вида:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/billing/subscriptions/zones" \<br>
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \<br>
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \<br>
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Данные `X-Auth-Email` - ваш емейл; `X-Auth-Key` - ваш `API key`.
В ответ будем иметь структуру вида:

```
{
    "success": true,
...
    "result": [
    {
        "zone_id": "023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353",
        "zone_name": "example.com"
    ...
    }],
...
}
```

Где `zone_name` - название вашего домена.

Comment: "{"result":[],"result_info":{"page":1,"per_page":20,"total_pages":0,"count":0,"total_count":0},"success":true,"errors":[],"messages":[]}"

Answer (score 0):

Запросом выше можно узнать id только зон, за которые вы платите. Чтобы узнать id любой зоны:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?name=somedomain.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

, где somedomain.com заменить на имя зоны, ид которой вы ищите.

Полный список зон:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

в cloudeflare - Overview - прокрутите вниз и с правой стороны увидите:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]